# How to get multiple Button Click Events in Python

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I am using following code to detect the co-ordinates in an image on the mouse button event:

```
plt.imshow(img,origin="upper")
connect('button_press_event', on_click)
plt.show()

def on_click(event):
    # get the x and y coords, flip y from top to bottom
    x, y = event.x, event.y
```

I have two problems here.

Firstly, 
while trying to return x,y in definition 'on_click' I have to store the variables x,y as they cannot be directly returned. Is there a better way to return these variables?

I have tried using the following function but it cannot return the value.

```
cid= implot.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onclick)
```

Secondly, I would like to get co-ordinates of multiple points from the same image.
Can you tell me how it can be done?

It is fine for me to display/plot the image by any different source. My major task is to read this co-ordinates from an image generated by OpenCV.

Comment: I use `print x,y` inside the function to show the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're wanting to interactively select a few points and then do something with the x, y data?

If so, you might consider using `plt.ginput()` instead.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title='Draw a 4-sided polygon by clicking points')
data = plt.ginput(4)

data.append(data[0])
ax.autoscale(False)
ax.fill(*zip(*data))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Using Ginput seems a very good option in my case. Also it has many other option which makes tasks easier. Thank you.